# How to filter part with regex

Tags: regex

I have a data which is :

```
- TEST 1
(O 1 9 14 17,231,=Defaut continuite
[Diag] = FAILED CONTINUITY

(O 72,225,=REF:STRAPP,COMPONENT TOP 
[Diag] = FAILED CONTINUITY BETWEEN : TC1.17,TC1.4
 
- TEST POPIYAX1245
(S 14,391
```

I want to extract a group of data with a regular expression like as below :

```
Match 1
Group 1.    (O
Group 2.    1 9 14 17,231
Group 3.    [Diag] = FAILED CONTINUITY


Match 2
Group 1.    (O
Group 2.    72,225
Group 3.    [Diag] = FAILED CONTINUITY BETWEEN : TC1.17,TC1.4

Match 3
Group 1.    (S
Group 2.    14,391
Group 3.
```

I use (^([S,O,B,C,F]).(.*[,=].*) to extract part but i can't do it like the example. Please check here https://regex101.com/r/nArj5i/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use 2 capturing groups with an optional 3rd group. (You can omit the comma's in the character class)

```
^(\([SOBCF]) (\d+(?:[ ,]\d+)*)(?:.*\r?\n(\[\w+] = .*))?
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(` capture **group 1**

  - `\([SOBCF]` Match `(` and one of the listed chars
- `)`  Close group 1 and match a space
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\d+(?:[ ,]\d+)*` Match 1+ digits and optionally repeat either a space or comma and 1+ digits
- `)` Close group 2
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `.*\r?\n` Match the rest of the line followed by a newline
  - `(\[\w+] = .*)` Capture **group 3**, match 1+ word chars between square brackets followed by a space, `=` and space and then the rest of the line
- `)?` Close group and make it optional

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/08w0M6/1)

Note that to match all content between the square brackets, you could also use a negated character class `\[[^\][]*]` instead of `\[\w+]`